# Change Proxy with VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am trying to change proxy with just a click using `vbs`. This is what I have got so far

```
dim oShell,strDesktop
set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

if msgbox("Turn Proxy on?", vbQuestion or vbYesNo) = vbYes then
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer", "192.168.80.45:80", "REG_SZ"
else
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"
end if
 strDesktop = oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") 
 oShell.AppActivate strDesktop
oShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

This script is changing the `Proxy` in `Configure Proxy Server` settings, but the actual change is not taking effect (I not able to browse any site). When I physically go to `Configure Proxy Server` and click on `ok`, the change is taking effect. Looks like despite of Updating the proxy value the change (Proxy) is not actually taking effect. Any idea how to set this to work

Comment: Maybe you should use a tool like [`Process Monitor`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see all of the changes being done when `[OK]` is clicked. It may be more than just this single registry key.